# Explain new rules for empty array index on a string with suitable examples

Tags: php, arrays, string, offset, php-7.1

I'm using **PHP 7.1.11**

Following are the quotes from the [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> **Warning** Writing to an out of range offset pads the string with spaces. Non-integer types are converted to integer. Illegal offset
>   type emits **E_NOTICE**. Only the first character of an assigned
>   string is used. As of PHP 7.1.0, assigning an empty string throws a
>   fatal error. Formerly, it assigned a NULL byte.
>
> **Note:** As of PHP 7.1.0, applying the empty index operator on a string throws a fatal error. Formerly, the string was silently
>   converted to an array.

I'm not able to understand the meaning of above two quotations from the manual.

As per my understanding I tried below code but I didn't receive any Notice or Fatal Error. This made me more confused about what the above two quotations are saying.

Consider the code I tried for which I didn't receive any Notice or Error :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$bar = "";
$foo[] = "Numba";
?>
```

It would be great if someone could please explain me the meaning of both the quotations from the manual with suitable examples demonstrating the same.

What does mean by **Null Byte**?

Thank You.

Comment: [I put 4 examples that shows the different behaviour on 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/HPBAg). Remove the comment to see the third. I'm too tired for a proper answer now, but I'll get back to you tomorrow, in cause nobody else answers. Ping me if I forget.

Comment: A null byte is `"\0"` or `"\x00"`